# iptables - Add additional allowed IPs

Tags: networking, iptables

This is what I have used as reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145933

So if I do:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s MY IP --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 21 -j DROP
```

I understand that only `MY IP` will be able to connect to port 21. But is there a way to add another accepted IP to that?

I've tried doing:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s MY OTHER IP --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

But it's still blocked, but I assume that's because the DROP is before. Could I append without dropping the DROP rule?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your approach. First, you `-I`nsert all rules. Without specifying an index, that means it’ll be inserted at the top. This is not what you want. When not inserting, use `-A`ppend, to clarify what you’re doing. This way, new rules will end up at the bottom.

It’s all about the order: Rules are processed top to bottom until a rule that ends processing matches. Something like `ACCEPT` or `DROP`.

What you want is something like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s MY IP --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 21 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT 2 -p tcp -s MY OTHER IP --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

It first recreates the state you initially had. Then, it inserts another rule so it’ll end up at position 2, moving other rules out of the way. That means the result is equivalent to doing this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s MY IP --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s MY OTHER IP --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 21 -j DROP
```